# How to fix returned error code 500 for login to website that required CSRF token

Tags: google-apps-script, csrf, csrf-token

I try to login to website with google apps script but stuck on code "var loginResponse = UrlFetchApp.fetch(loginURL,loginOptions);" which return error code 500.

I tried to get all necessary data in chrome dev tool and put in my code but still no luck.
Edit: I added function grabData to grab the token. I saw the logger.log return different token, maybe that's why I can't get to login.

```
function getData() {
  var loginURL = "https://example.com/login";
  var token = grabData("https://example.com/login",
      '<meta name="csrf-token" content="',
      '">');
Logger.log(token); // Logger 1st
  var dataURL = "https://example.com/c/daftar";
  var loginPayload = {
     '_token' : grabData("https://example.com/login",'<meta name="csrf-token" content="','">');,
     'email' : 'example@email.com',
     'password' : '123456'
  };

Logger.log(loginPayload);  //logger 2nd
  var headers = {
 'Connection':'keep-alive',
 'Accept':'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3',
    'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Cookie':'XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6InJHYzBMamNXc1wveDRDaVRvcCtibnF3PT0iLCJ2YWx1ZSI6ImkzMFFrUUR0MVBQdTVOU0NLTWoyRmk5OElxNWQrMDVVU2llMlNrQjFXOSs0TjVTRmNZTmo0MUFQZVRGS21cL3lFRFN4R1pveDlBS2x1TmxDVVZ6YUJUdz09IiwibWFjIjoiNzVhYjQ2NDUzYjBhNmE0OTFjYzk2MGNhNGE3YTM1NDRmYjA4NTgyN2EyN2EwZTllYTE1ZDM4YzQ0NjA5ZmM3YyJ9; xxx=eyJpdiI6IkIwdFVjd2xwSXZwY3dld0k3K2F1QVE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiTXBzZGREZFwvak91TllaaktkalwvR1o0RFQzamc5bXd2UmY3WW94UWhOdlQzeDJTTFVKZ2l2NUsySmZTdzBNYTVITDk5b0JqanQ3cFBYVlJiaWlxU1wvSlE9PSIsIm1hYyI6IjA5MDdkMzVhOTNhZWU5MWIxMGNlMTFiOWExNjJhZjVmY2VjYmJlMWZkYzg1MjMxNzhjOTcwNzIxZWJlMjlmMWUifQ%3D%3D',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.100 Safari/537.36'
  };

  var loginOptions = {
    'payload':loginPayload,
    'method':'POST',
    'headers': headers
    'followRedirects':false
  };

  var loginResponse = UrlFetchApp.fetch(loginURL,loginOptions);
  var loginHeaders = loginResponse.getAllHeaders();
  var cookie = [loginResponse.getAllHeaders()["Set-Cookie"]];
  cookie[0] = cookie[0].split(";")[0]; 
  cookie = cookie.join(";");  
  var dataHeaders = {'Cookie':cookie};
  var dataOptions = {'method':'get','headers':dataHeaders};
  var dataResponse = UrlFetchApp.fetch(dataURL,dataOptions);

  Logger.log(dataResponse);
}
```

The dataResponse will not return any log until I successfully login the website, is there any wrong with my code?

Comment: You misspelled `followRedirects` (should be capital R). Does this solver the problem?

Comment: Hi  ziganotschka, thanks for your fast reply, I had corrected the spelling, but not yet solve the problem